# "Cloud SDK missing" error on Eclipse in Linux

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-tools

I'm getting an error on Eclipse Oxygen running on Linux when I try to create a Google App Engine project.
I've installed the Google SDK and I can run gcloud from the terminal. But I can't create an App Engine Eclipse project because Eclipse can't find the Cloud SDK. I'm supposed to set the location in the Google Cloud Platform preferences. But where are these preferences located in Eclipse?

Comment: How is it that you know you're supposed to set the location in the preferences?

Comment: This is the error message in full: Cannot create an App Engine Eclipse project because the Cloud SDK could not be found. Install it from https://cloud.google.com/sdk and set the location in the Google Cloud Platform preferences.

Answer (score 3):

I found how to change it. I had to go to **Window** » **Preferences** and under the Google Cloud Tools tab, I could change the directory of the SDK location. In my case, the SDK location directory was incorrect, causing this error.

Comment: This was the same case for me. In Mac, Go to Eclipse >> Preferences, set the google cloud install. This might happen due to installing through command prompt.